# TouchGFX displaying "inf" on a Textbox being updated only with float values

Tags: touchgfx

I'm constantly updating a Textbox with a 15 buffer size wildcard, and another separated issue related to the application makes the value go up to 42949672.95  which still should be inside the buffer size range, but the buffer displays "inf" when set to write that value with snprintFloat on a ".1f" format. My question is regarding what criteria or threshold does TouchGFX need to assign that inf automatically on the textbox?, rather than the seemingly valid (according to buffer size) number passed as parameter.

The value is usually capped at 999999.9 and in that scenario it displays the value accordingly, so I haven't tried going beyond that value for the moment.
My TouchGFX version is 4.18.1
The board is custom